# What to do when a Muslim convert husband claimed to be a non-Muslim out of anger?

Tags: nikah, husband-wife, kufr, anger

I’m a Muslim. I’m married to a man who converted to Islam before we got married. We have now been married for 11 years. In one of his mobile text messages to me, out of anger he said that he is not a Muslim.

I have a few questions:

1. Does this immediately make him a non-Muslim?
2. If so, and he claimed he said it out of anger, what should he do?
3. What happens to our marriage if he is no longer a Muslim? Do I have to divorce him?

Comment: intentions matter in this case, so you have to make sure if he really meant it by heart

Comment: For the third question: your marriage becomes null and void if he is no longer a muslim. A muslim woman's marriage to a non-muslim is invalid.

Comment: However, at first, convince him to do "tawbah" (repentance) from the heart, and reinforce his shahadah asap. Then consult with a knowledgeable AND practicing a'lim about the situation. Determining someone as kafir quickly is a very very serious offense for a Muslim person. ALLAH knows the best.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your question that you inquired if this immediately makes him a non-Muslim or not, so, as a rule, (as far as I know) it doesn’t need to pass the time to become non-Muslim, actually whoever confesses that he is not a Muslim anymore, then we ought to consider him as a non-Muslim.

With respect to your second question that you inquired if so, and he claimed he said it out of anger, what he should do, then your marriage won’t be valid anymore.
And eventually with respect to your third question, I ought to mention that as I illustrated above, it is considered as a void marriage, Since (according to Shia Islam) it is not a valid marriage. Thus, rationally there mustn't be the necessity to divorce…

---

**Reference(s):**

- [www.wikifeqh.ir](http://www.wikifeqh.ir/)
- [ezdevaj7hamedan.blogfa.com](http://ezdevaj7hamedan.blogfa.com/post/52)

Answer (score 0):

1. Declaring himself a non-Muslim only indicates his shallowness of belief in the first place. His anger with you has nothing to do with the religion.
2. He is free to believe or not believe since the Qur'an says 'everyone
   to his belief (faith).
3. Divorcing him just because he says he is not a Muslim would be a bad decision. You believe what you believe and let him do the same. There is no compulsion.
4. Try reconciling your differences without bringing religion in the picture.

May Allah be with you.

Answer (score 0):

- No this doesn't make him a non-Muslim (if said in anger)

  - He should seek forgiveness of Allah
  - As I said he isn't a non Muslim so no threat to your marriage (by the way it will still be valid - deduced from Ahadith)

The Anger is a part of shaytan (Satan), so whatever a person says in anger doesn't hold validity,(because the person doesn't think of the consequences of his words when he/she is in anger.) Satan uses anger to spread mischief, mistrust, envy and all the bad things. There is a hadith that if you suppress anger then you get a reward for it, because it isn't an easy task to do so. Your role as a fiancee is to help him out of anger. by simply asking refuge with Allah for you both from Satan.

Answer (score 0):

Your husband did a very great mistake by voicing out those words, and he has now regretted and claimed he did it out of anger.  He is human and he is bound to make mistakes for sure, because Allah said "son of Adam is a sinner, but among them the best is those who repent with sincere repentance to Allah."

He should repent to Allah and ask for forgiveness because Allah is *Ghafuuru Raheem*.